# S.M.A.R.T. tool displaying SDD/HDD health status in system tray

Tags: windows, open-source, hard-disk, system-monitor, disk-analysis

Please recommend a Windows tool capable of the following:

- monitoring and displaying the S.M.A.R.T. values of internal disk drives (SDD/HDD)
- displaying the overall health status as an icon in the system tray (i.e. green status icon indicating all values are good)
- Ideally the program should be lightweight and FOSS.

---

I have tested most of the free Windows tools in this Wikipedia comparison listing:
[Comparison of S.M.A.R.T. tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools)

The program coming closest to said requirements is [CrystalDiskInfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrystalDiskMark#CrystalDiskInfo). However it features a system tray status icon, which unfortunately indicates the disk temperature rather than the S.M.A.R.T. health status: [image: screenshot] I couldn't find a preference setting to change this.

Do you know any other program meeting these requirements ?

---

**Rationale**: The idea is that the tool alerts the user when the SMART values degrade, so that the disk can be replaced before data corruption occurs. I am aware that catastrophic failures can still happen without such prior notice, but it's certainly better than nothing. And yes, some tools are probably capable of alerting the user in other ways than a system tray icon (e.g. via sound or eMail), but a green/red system tray icon would be my preferred method of alert.